# Fullcalendar Year View in Angular 8

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

How to get a view of all month in a single page in Fullcalendar.
I have installed the fullcalendar through npm and using the dayGridPlugin to get the output.
It's rendering a calendar in monthly view, however no where I found how to get the yearly view

Comment: what do you mean by yearly view ?

Comment: Current year months in a single page.
For now it's showing only one month in a page and we have to navigate to next month using the button

Comment: you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-calendar-year-view

Comment: I am using this: https://fullcalendar.io/

Comment: fullCalendar doesn't have a "year" view. All the available view types are listed at https://fullcalendar.io/docs . There's nowhere you can go to get one, unless some 3rd party has already written a custom plugin and made it available to download for free. You'd have to do some googling to find out. Your other alternative is to write your own custom view - but it's not a simple task. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-view-with-js